# EJS Node.JS Express - css path issue when url with more than 1 parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express, ejs

First sorry for my poor english !

Well, I am developping a web application using NodeJS / Express and EJS as template engine.

I am currently facing an issue.

Here is my folder hierarchy

```
App folder/
|___ server.js /
|___ node_modules /
|___ required /
     |___ bootstrap /
     |___ css /
     |___ font-awesome /
     |___ images /
|___ views /
     |___ default.ejs
     |___ home.ejs
     |___ mission.ejs
     |___ mission /
          |___ create.ejs
          |___ delete.ejs
```

Here is my **server.js** configuration:

```
// Setup le serveur http
var app = express();

var code = 4567;
////// CONFIGURATION
// Définit le chemin relatif pour tous les fichiers utilisés dans l'app
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
console.log(__dirname + "");
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');


app.get('/:app', function(req, res) {

  if (req.session.logged == false) {
    res.render('login.ejs');
  }else{

    if(api.page_exist(req.params.app)){
      res.render('default.ejs', {app:req.params.app});
    }else{

      /*console.log("La page demandée n'existe pas"); */
      res.redirect('/home');
    }

  }

});

app.get('/:app/:action', function(req,res){

  if(api.page_folder_exist(req.params.app,req.params.action)){

    console.log(__dirname);
    res.render('default.ejs', {app:req.params.app, action:req.params.action});


  }else{

      res.redirect('/');
  }

});
```

Basically, I have two routes : `/:app/`  I load the value into the template default.ejs and I include `app.ejs` where app can be "home", "mission"... etc...
This route is working well

The other route is : `/:app/:action`  where *:app* defines the folder for example the folder *mission* and *action* defines the action for example *create*. Using the URL `/mission/create` includes the template `/mission/create.ejs` in `default.ejs` and display it.

It's working but I have an issue about the path to load the css. By using this route, the browser try to get : `http://localhost:8333/mission/required/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` instead of `http://localhost:8333/required/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` like in the first route.

Here is how I link my css files :

```
<link href="required/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="required/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="required/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Do you have any idea ?
I assume it is about my route configuration but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you might want to try this.

> Express looks up the files in the order in which you set the static
>   directories with the express.static middleware function.
>
> To create a virtual path prefix (where the path does not actually
>   exist in the file system) for files that are served by the
>   express.static function, specify a mount path for the static
>   directory, as shown below:

```
app.use('/required', express.static('required'));
```

*this should probably replace this in your code*

```
// Définit le chemin relatif pour tous les fichiers utilisés dans l'app
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

> Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory from the
>   /static path prefix.

For example:

```
http://localhost:8333/required/bootstrap/somefile.css
http://localhost:8333/required/css/somefile.css
http://localhost:8333/required/font-awesome/somefile.css
```

[More Info on this here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. Replacing `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` by `app.use('/required', express.static('required')); `  solved my problem ! I also had to add '/' when I linked css files `<link href="/required/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 7):

In html page(jade/ejs/html) remove 2 dots in path **..**/public while including the css and javactipts

```
ex:
Wrong:
<link href="../public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

Right:
<link href="/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: thank you. you saved me another hours of a headache. this is the exact mistake I have and now fixed. thanks to you.